# how to trigger another clk in mainclk (verilog)

Tags: verilog, hdl, quartus

I wrote somekind of prescaler in verilog to make sclk_adc signal from clk_i. 
by now my code looks like:

```
always @(posedge clk_i)
begin
//generation of sclk_adc
end
```

[image]

now i wonder is there any probability to load shift registers on pos/negedge of generated clock in always @(posedge clk_i) block?

When i wrote this outside the main always block

```
always @(negedge sclk_adc)
begin
    transdata = transtmp;
    dataInCh[ch_cnt][15:0] = transdata;
end 

always @(posedge sclk_adc)
begin
    dout = shiftOut [ch_cnt] [15];
    shiftOut [ch_cnt][15:0] = { shiftOut[ch_cnt] [14:0], 1'b0};
end
```

It is simulated well in the GTKwave, but quartus started to complain about multiply reference to dout (my output), deservedly, i think.
So it seems like i have to load them in main always block, but when i add those lines there, shift registers start to load with clk_i, not with the sclk_adc what is logical, but how to avoid this?
Please, provide me any clue, thanks

Comment: You should share all the code you can. You haven't shared code that shows two references to `dout`, so it's hard for us to comment on how you can improve your code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NXUHLb3u

Comment: now it is here (i am sorry it is my first verilog code. it is driver for adc circuit). But i faced another problem :c I almost get what i wanted [link](http://www.picshare.ru/view/8898888/) i needed dout loaded WITH posedge sclk_adc and transdata shift WITH negedge sclk. But they made it at another clk_i after event of pos/negedge, why? help me to explain this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> I almost get what i wanted link i needed dout loaded WITH posedge sclk_adc

You can just update `dout` on the edge of `sclk_adc`:

```
always @(posedge sclk_adc) 
    begin
    dout <= shiftOut [ch_cnt] [15];
    end
```

But if you do this, you can only update `dout` in this always block. You can use an asynchronous reset if you are concerned that your reset signal won't be asserted long enough to see an edge of the slow clock:

```
always @(posedge sclk_adc or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin 
        dout <= 0;
    else begin
        dout <= shiftOut [ch_cnt] [15];
    end
end
```

You can't reset `dout` in the always block timed by `clk_i` if you're also going to set it in the block timed by `sclk_adc`.

Alternatively, since you are generating `sclk_adc` using a counter timed by `clk_i`, you could just arrange to assert `sclk_adc` one cycle earlier than you are doing now. It's quite common when generating slow clocks to actually generate several clocks at the same frequency, but delayed from each other by 1 or more cycles of the master clock, to allow timing different events on different *phases* of the slow clock.

Comment: According to you i will rewrite `dout` like this
`assign dout = shiftOut [15];
assign out_next = { shiftOut[14:0], 1'b0};`
to not mention it in main block and will make another always with sclk_adc. but it still mystery why my pos and neg detectors did not work. Anyway, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well i beat this one. I just needed to built rising and falling edge detector

all i neeg is that few lines

```
reg    main_reg;
wire    pos_sclk, neg_sclk; 
assign  pos_sclk = sclk_adc & ~main_reg;
assign  neg_sclk = ~sclk_adc & main_reg;
```

and in main clk block

```
main_reg <= sclk_adc;
```